# System.Data.SqlClient in EFCore dll not supported in .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0, sqlclient

Alright, quick rundown of what is going on:

- We have a very old legacy system that we are updating to .NET Framework 4.7.2 (yes, before you ask, the migration to 4.7.2 is already complete and running just fine)
- At the same time we are building new applications in .NET Core, and for these new applications we built a DAL using netstandard 2.0 and EF Core.
- When we wrap up the DAL in dlls and attempt to us it in the .NET Framework 4.7.2 application, we get an exception thrown at run time when the DataContext is generated (specifically at `var options = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(300)).Options;` with the following for `ex.Message`:

> System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

I have reviewed a bunch of threads and am aware that there seems to be an issue with this dll and a few others when using netstandard dlls inside a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application, but if anyone has any sort of help on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** Changing the EF Core to either frameworks 2.2.0 or 2.0.0 DID NOT resolve the issue. When the SqlConnection is called, it still breaks:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)   

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
```

Comment: what version of EntityFrameworkCore are you using? see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437064/9534819) helps..

Comment: I have actually looked at that and am working on that potential solution now. We were on 2.1.3. I attempted to update to 2.2.0 (just completed and it didn't work), and I am going to try to downgrade to 2.0.0 now.

Comment: EF Core issues should be reported to Microsoft https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues

Comment: reported at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14880 already