# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform - Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` (3.1) in a .NET Core 3.1 library. This library gets loaded at runtime by an executable .NET Core project by using:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom('some.dll');
```

When trying to retrieve data from a `DbSet`, I get the following exception:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.'

I guess it has something to do with loading the library at runtime, but I don't get why?

I tried various different things, like overriding the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` library with Version 1.1 or 2.0, but without any success.

Comment: refer URLs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355530/system-data-sqlclient-is-not-supported-on-this-platform  may help you

Comment: No, they are facing a different problem, which produces a similar error.

Comment: Hi @JonasHammerschmidt How did you solved this problem? We are also facing the same issue when an app loads our DLL using `Assembly.LoadFrom()`

Answer (score 5):

I received this message:
`System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.`

**My solution:**

- Add the latest version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient as a NuGet dependency (Current v.2.1.2)
- If you are using the `Newtonsoft` namespace, e.g. Newtonsoft.Json and this namespace could not be found after installing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, then get the Newtonsoft.Json dependency from NuGet.

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround I found so far was to add a
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` reference to the executable projects' properties file.

Not exactly elegant; but it works.

Comment: Are you keeping or removing the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` dependency? I've updated everything to .Net5.0 and `SqlClient` seems to be the one thing that isn't yet updated.

Comment: This also worked for me - I removed it as I was using POSTGreSQL and thought it not needed. Apparently it is...

Answer (score 1):

I solved that by using System.Data.SqlClient package, and pass the costom SqlConnection to dbContext as the following example:

```
//this ConnectionString for database in sqlserver
var ConnectionString = @"Server=tcp:192.168.1.102,1433;Initial Catalog=db_name`enter code here`;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=test;Password=test;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=50;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";

//Creat Connection with sqlClient in System.Data.SqlClient .dll
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection TestConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

//Create OptionBuilder
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(TestConnection);

//Create dbContext and pass connection builder that has sqlConnection
var dbContext = new AppDbContextMeClient(optionsBuilder);

//then call tables
var Students = dbContext.StudentsEntities.All();
```

Comment: Switching to a different driver that is no longer actively maintained is not so much a solution as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was solved by simply re-uploading the bin folder (not only the .dll file) again to the production server.