# Getting error "System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, devexpress, visual-studio-2022, winapp

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with a Windows application and DevExpress 22.22.

When I created a setup package and ran the application shortcut, the main form appears with no problem. But when I open any form using a data table, this error appears:

> System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

[image]

**Note**: I'm working through the Visual Studio no problem occurred, and program runs normal.

I use the following:

- Visual Studio 2022, C#
- .NET Core 7.0
- Entity Framework Core 7
- DevExpress 22.2
- SQL Server
- Windows 10 platform and setup installed onto Windows 10

Best regards

Comment: There are number of answers you can try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355530/system-data-sqlclient-is-not-supported-on-this-platform